# How i change scripts in my custom theme in drupal 6

Tags: 6, javascript, theming

i write a custom theme for my site and i want to remove `misc/tableheader.js` script from site scripts and add my own `tableheader.js` instead.
is any way to i do it without changing original `misc/tableheader.js` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while but I think this is the way to do it in Drupal 6:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Add your JS
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/my-tableheader.js'));

  // Get the cached JS
  $js = drupal_add_js();

  // Remove the core tableheader file
  unset($js['module']['misc/tableheader.js']); 

  // Change the scripts var to reflect the new array
  $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $js);
}
```

Comment: when i used your code no scripts includes in result page, `$vars['scripts']` is string not array, while when `$vars['scripts'] = $js;` we set it as an array and it's not true, and on the result page its print only 'Array' instead of scripts links

Comment: Try changing the name of the function to `phptemplate_preprocess_page` and clearing the caches, does that help?

Comment: steal not working, in my page `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" ref="/fancy/jquery.fancybox.css?o" />  Array  </head>`

Comment: i find what is your code wrong, we should write `$vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $js);` instead of `$vars['scripts'] = $js;` and `'misc/tableheader.js'` script is child of `module` not `core`, thx you, please change these in your code

Comment: My bad sorry about that :) I'll change the code in the answer for future visitors